# Debug client restful service on android

Tags: android, rest, debugging

When I was creating my app I faced with problem for debugging my 
`rest` 
client in android. I created restful service on my leptop and when I want  reqest  write  I do something like that 
`localhost:8080/test1/rest/flight/test`,
 if I'm right on my client I  should write adres my PC instead
 `localhost:8080` 
but I dont have static IP adress. What I can do, for debug my client?

Answer (score 0):

the local host IP is always 127.0.0.1

Comment: but i use other device for client